# Help to understand better A - A' = {}

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi is my first post so thank you in advance.

In operations with Sets...
An exercise of True or False: A - A' = {}

I mark as false as I view it as A = {1,2} - A'{3,4} would be = to A = {1,2}
But looks like I'm wrong, and the thought here would be that since we have nothing to remove from A, would result in an empty set.

I appreciate any insight to help understand it.

Comment: This might depend on the definitions of $-$ and $'$ you are using. By my eye, "false" is correct, because to me
$$
A-B = \{ x \in A \mid x \not \in B \}
$$
and
$$
A' = \{x \in \text{our universal set} \mid x \not \in A\}
$$
so $A - A' = A$ (since $A,A'$ share nothing in common). This is even more obvious with the alternative definition of
$$
A-B = A \cap B'
$$
so
$$
A - A' = A \cap (A')' = A \cap A = A
$$

Comment: If $A'=\{3,4\}$, then this statement is indeed false. However, your question says "$A'\{3,4\}$", the meaning of which is unclear.